# PHP how to get value from array if key is in a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a key stored in a variable like so:

```
$key = 4;
```

I tried to get the relevant value like so:

```
$value = $array[$key];
```

but it failed. Help.

Comment: What do you mean "failed," any errors?

Comment: Are you sure there's a value in $array[4]? Because your syntax is correct - look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: Could you add some more details, for example which is the contents of $array ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine, make sure that key you specify *really exists in the array or such key has a value in your array* eg:

```
$array = array(4 => 'Hello There');
print_r(array_keys($array));
// or better
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

**Now:**

```
$key = 4;
$value = $array[$key];
print $value;
```

**Output:**

```
Hello There
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$value = ( array_key_exists($key, $array) && !empty($array[$key]) ) 
         ? $array[$key] 
         : 'non-existant or empty value key';
```

Answer (score 2):

As others stated, it's likely failing because the requested key doesn't exist in the array. I have a helper function here that takes the array, the suspected key, as well as a default return in the event the key does not exist.

```
    protected function _getArrayValue($array, $key, $default = null)
    {
        if (isset($array[$key])) return $array[$key];
        return $default;
    }
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you intended.

```
$array = array('value-0', 'value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3', 'value-4', 'value-5' /* … */);
$key = 4;
$value = $array[$key];
echo $value; // value-4
```

But maybe there is no element with the key `4`. If you want to get the fiveth item no matter what key it has, you can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$value = array_slice($array, 4, 1);
```