# GET_CONTENT name from txt file

Tags: php

i have this list on name.txt file :

```
"name1":"Robert"
"name2":"George"
"name3":"Flophin"
"name4":"Fred"
```

in a web page i need a php code that takes only the name of the person by the name 1 2 3 4 id.

I've use this in `test.php?id=name2`

```
$Text=file_get_contents("./name.txt"); 
if(isset($_GET["id"])){ 
    $id = $_GET["id"]; 
    $regex = "/".$id."=\'([^\']+)\'/"; 
    preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match); 
    $fid=$Match[1][0]; 
    echo $fid; 
} else { 
    echo ""; 
}
```

The result should be `George` ,
how do i change this to work??

Mabe is another way to do this more simply?

Comment: I've fixed some of your indentation so the code is at least easier to understand, but please put in some effort in your questions :). For isntance, what does it do currently? Also, you can add some debugging (`echo`'s for instance) to see where you arrive in your code, what goes on, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres an ugly solution to your problem, which you can loop trough.

And [Here's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) a reference to the explode function.

```
<?php

$text = '"name1":"Robert"
"name2":"George"
"name3":"Flophin"
"name4":"Fred"';

$x = explode("\n", $text);
$x = explode(':', $x[1]);

echo $x[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file=file('name.txt');

$id = $_GET["id"]; 

$result=explode(':',$file[$id-1]);

echo $result[1];
```

Edit: $result[1] if you want just name.

Answer (score 0):

Load the text file into an array; see [Text Files and Arrays in PHP](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p7.html) as an example.

Once the array is loaded you can reference the array value directly, e.g. $fid = $myArray['name' . $id]. Please refer to [PHP how to get value from array if key is in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281526/php-how-to-get-value-from-array-if-key-is-in-a-variable) as an example.